# JQuery Doesn't Respond After Swal Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am having a problem with my JQuery code, after swal alert, it doesn't append value to the inputs.

What I do first I check if the value of the start_date is Empty if yes then swal alert, then when I select it the values won't append to the boxes...

```
function ChangeDate() {
    debugger;
    var Startdate = document.getElementById("lease_stattdate").value;
    var thisDate = new Date(Startdate);
    var month = thisDate.getMonth();
    var year = thisDate.getFullYear();
    var dateSelected = thisDate.getUTCDate();
    var firstDay = 1;
    var LastDate = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);
    var LastDay = LastDate.getDate();
    var today = new Date();
    var TodayMonth = today.getMonth();
    var date = true;
    if (month <= TodayMonth) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        swal("Error!", "Please select upcoming month!", "warning");
        $('#lease_stattdate').val('');
        $('#renewal_notice').val('');
        $('#end_date').val('');
        $('#termination_notice').val('');
        window.location.reload();
    }
    if (month > TodayMonth && dateSelected > firstDay) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        swal("Error!", "Please select first day of the month!", "warning");
        $('#lease_stattdate').val('');
        $('#renewal_notice').val('');
        $('#end_date').val('');
        $('#termination_notice').val('');
        window.location.reload();
    }
    if (month > TodayMonth && dateSelected == firstDay) {
        var tempday = 15;
        var nextdate = new Date(year, month + 23, tempday);
        var NXmonth = nextdate.getMonth();
        var NXyear = nextdate.getFullYear();
        var terminateday = new Date(NXyear, NXmonth + 1, 0).getDate();
        var exitdate = new Date(NXyear, NXmonth, terminateday).toLocaleDateString('en-ZA');
        var renewalNotice = new Date(NXyear, NXmonth-2, 1).toLocaleDateString('en-ZA');
        var terminationNotice = new Date(NXyear, NXmonth, 1).toLocaleDateString('en-ZA');

        $('#renewal_notice').val(renewalNotice);
        $('#end_date').val(exitdate);
        $('#termination_notice').val(terminationNotice);
    }
}
```

Comment: `then when I select it the values won't append to the boxes...` it's not clear what you mean by this from the small JS code sample you've provided. Can you please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a snippet in the question so we can help you debug this.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at StartThisSessionTimer (ApplicationUpdateTenantLeaseDetails?q=W8KoKYEec%2Fv0my%2BFDkETnvpQjSetXVvoqvZmbypNjZXFMVe8O7CXU532RR8UCWd2lLhidzxiljv0dzeKi%2FnHqA%3D%3D:3534:9)
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: that was my problem I just fixed it....

Comment: $('#renewal_notice').val(renewalNotice);
            $('#end_date').val(exitdate);
            $('#termination_notice').val(terminationNotice);

Comment: document.getElementById("renewal_notice").value = renewalNotice;
            document.getElementById("end_date").value = exitdate;
            document.getElementById("termination_notice").value = terminationNotice;

Comment: I replaced the code with the other part it worked

Comment: `window.location.reload();` - looks like it reloads the window after you make changes.   Did you get your issue sorted?